Updating wagtailcore.PageRevision in a old migration file
According to Wagtail 4.0, PageRevision has been replaced with Revision.
Now I have a very old migration file that has a lazy reference to it:
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                ('revision', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='wagtailcore.pagerevision')),
                # other fields
            ],
        ),
    ]

and I have 98 migration files on top of that. Everything is working fine and I can create new migrations without any errors. But as soon as I try to migrate back to any number, I get:
ValueError: The field myapp.MyModel.revision was declared with a lazy reference to 'wagtailcore.pagerevision', but app 'wagtailcore' doesn't provide model 'pagerevision'.

which makes sense. I've tried to fix it by replacing the old reference with wagtailcore.revision but I still get an error. Also tried to update MyModel so it references the new wagtail.models.Revision but no new migration is detected and I still get the error:
ValueError: The field myapp.MyModel.revision was declared with a lazy reference to 'wagtailcore.revision', but app 'wagtailcore' doesn't provide model 'revision'.

Any thoughts on how to fix this properly?
